# If $Y$ is a function of $x$ , i.e. $y=f(x)$,

Tags: functions

I am struggling with this problem. If $y=f(x)$, then if $y=3x$. Then if we divide by both sides, then $x=y/3$, and so does it mean $x$ is a function of $y$?

I think changing the order is not allowed. But I am not sure. Please help.

Comment: The set of points $\{(x,y)~:~x,y\in\Bbb R,~~3x=y\}$ can be written as the set of points $\{(x,3x)~:~x\in\Bbb R\}$ or as $\{(\frac{y}{3},y)~:~y\in\Bbb R\}$.  All three describe the same set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, yes. You have to be careful: what you are using here is that $y=3x\color{red}\iff x=\frac y3$.

It is also true that if $y=x^3$, then $x=\sqrt[3]y$ (assuming that we are working on $\Bbb R$ here). However, it is *not* true that, in $\Bbb R$, we have $x=y^2\iff y=\sqrt x$. Nevertheless, this *is* true if we are working on $[0,\infty)$ instead. So, on $[0,\infty)$ if $y=x^2$, then $y$ is a function of $x$ and $x$ is a function of $y$ (since $x=\sqrt y$ then).

Comment: So other than [0, infinity), it can't be reversed right?

Comment: Why not? In $[1,\infty)$ you also have $x=y^2\iff y=\sqrt x$.

Comment: Hi José, quick question: is it correct to interpret the sentence “$y$ is a function of $x$” as “there exists a function $f$ such that $y=f(x)$”? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TaylorRendon Yes, that is correct.